# setText in afterTextChanged in TextWatcher makes holding backspace not working

Tags: android

I'm using `addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher)` to my `editText` for some currency format.
There is `setText()` in `afterTextChanged` in my `TextWatcher`.

```
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        et.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        (snipped)
        et.setText(someText);
        (snipped)

        et.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
```

[image]
The problem is that even though holding backspace **I can delete only one character.** I found that `setText` in the `afterTextChanged` makes holding backspace not working.
I don't know the exact mechanism but it seems `setText` push up backspace.

In addition it seems this doesn't happen in Android 7.0 but happens android 8.0 and 9.0.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Same issue here! Was you able to figure it out?

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO. I'm sorry but I couldn't find the solution. I don't have enough time to dig into this problem.

Comment: I am not sure what causes the issue, but `editable.replace(0, editable.length, replacedText)` could be helpful for some cases. FYI for others.

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention, do NOT `setInputType` on the EditText if you expect `editable.replace(0, editable.length, replacedText)` to be helpful for prevent the backspace to be pushed up.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to know when the backspace is pressed:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {                 
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {  
        editText.setText(editText.getText().tostring()); // gets the current text and sets it again
    }
    return false;       
}
});
```

You said it works only once. By doing this if you press it it gives you another chance by setting text again and then you can press backspace only once again.

Comment: I want to delete characters as long as holding backspace and above code doesn't work.